# How to use Autofac to register components in non referencing projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, autofac

Ho do you register components with `Autofac` without referencing all the projects in your web application?

I have layered my application in the following format:

- Website
- Tasks
- Services

Please use the code below for my explanations.

My controller class:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
     private IMyTask myTask;

     public MyController(IMyTask myTask)
     {
          this.myTask = myTask;
     }

     public ActionResult Index()
     {
          HomeViewModel model = myTask.Index();

          return View(model);
     }
}
```

My task class:

```
public class MyTask : IMyTask
{
     private IMyService myService;

     public MyTask(IMyService myService)
     {
          this.myService = myService;
     }

     public HomeViewModel Index()
     {
          HomeViewModel homeViewModel = new HomeViewModel();

          // Do something with myService

          return homeViewModel;
     }
}
```

My Index action method would call a method from my task class, this would create my view model and return it to the action method.

I am only referencing the required references in each project, I don't want to reference any project that shouldn't be there.  For example, my website will only reference `MyProject.Tasks`.  And `MyProject.Tasks` will only reference `MyProject.Services`.  My website will not contain references to both these projects.

I'm struggling to understand how I would use `Autofac` to register the above dependencies seeing that I don't reference both projects in my website?

Normally I would do it like this in `Application_Start`:

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

builder.RegisterType<MyTask>().As<IMyTask>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
builder.RegisterType<MyService>().As<IMyService>().InstancePerHttpRequest();

IContainer container = builder.Build();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

I have tried this from my website:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad("MyProject.Services"))
     .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
     .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

...but it won't work because I did not reference `MyProject.Services` in the website.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: If your website doesn't use services the it doesn't make sense to register anything from it. They should be registered in the tasks project. Not sure what your design looks like but you might need to introduce some initialization in your tasks project.

Comment: Yes I thought about that but will I need to pass around the builder instance?

Comment: Try creating one or more [Module](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/StructuringWithModules) projects which references all or groups of these libraries and do registration from that.

Comment: Yeah, or have modules within each project that you register. For example a module in Tasks that you register in website.

Comment: @Mathew - Documentation has been moved.  Also, consider making your comment an answer so that it can be marked as the answer, if appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I normally use external XML configuration file for registering (nearly) all the Autofac stuffs.
It makes me more sense and introduces means like XML config transformations.
It also avoids all unnecessary project references.

For example:

```
public static class AutofacConfig
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        ConfigurationBuilder config = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        config.AddXmlFile(@"Config\Autofac.config");

        IContainer container = builder.Build();

        AutofacServiceLocator serviceLocator = new AutofacServiceLocator(container);
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => serviceLocator);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure about the "minus", but the external config file is the most robust way to avoid unwanted project references and therefore maintain loose coupling. There of course must be the service binary dll file present in the bin directory.

Answer (score -1):

For register components with Autofac without referencing all the projects in your web application do this:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    var assemblies = GetAssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory(x => x.FullName.StartsWith("Your service name"));
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies).AsImplementedInterfaces();
    builder.Populate(services);
    return builder.Build();
}

private static Assembly[] GetAssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory(Func<AssemblyName, bool> condition)
{
    var baseDirectoryPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; // or directory with your dll
    Func<string, bool> isAssembly = file => string.Equals(Path.GetExtension(file), ".dll", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    return Directory.GetFiles(baseDirectoryPath)
          .Where(isAssembly)
          .Where(f => condition(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(f)))
          .Select(Assembly.LoadFrom)
          .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: add description